# edittext does not grow downwards, text goes out of the visible area

Tags: android, android-layout

Problem :- In case i have more than 1 line in my edittext, the previous line goes out of the visible area. I was expecting it to grow downwards so that all lines are visible.

Xml for my compound control which has this edittext:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/composite_control_layout"
    android:background="@null"
    tools:context="com.gp.app.professionalpa.layout.ListItemLayout" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/compositeControlAddItem"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:text="@string/plus"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/compositeControlImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/note_image"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/compositeControlAddItem"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/compositeControlAddItem"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <!--  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/compositeControlBulletButton"
        android:layout_width="35dip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/composite_control_height"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/set_importance"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_black_bullet_point" /> -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/compositeControlTextBox"
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/composite_control_height"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/add_note"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/compositeControlAddItem"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/compositeControlAddItem"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine|textAutoComplete|textCapSentences"
        android:maxLines="7"
        android:maxLength="200"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/compositeControlDeleteItem"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/compositeControlTextBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/compositeControlTextBox"
        android:text="@string/minus"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity i am creating this compound contrl using the following code:-

```
private void addNewListItem() 
{
    ListViewItemLayout currentAddedListItem = new ListViewItemLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.alignWithParent =  true;

    if(lastAddedListItem != null)
    {
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastAddedListItem.getId());
    }

    currentAddedListItem.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    activityLayout.addView(currentAddedListItem, listItems.size());

    listItems.add(currentAddedListItem);

    Button button = currentAddedListItem.getAddButton();

    lastAddedListItem = currentAddedListItem;
}
```

Image showing that the previous lines becomes invisible in case edittext enters new line:-

[image: image showing edittext not growing downwards and text becoming invisible]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing the layout height of your edit text ... prob looks with your composite height used

Comment: thanks a lot, changed edittext height to wrap_content it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**just use android:paddingEnd = "your "